# Set actionbar backgroung when using toolbar

Tags: java, android, android-actionbar

I have been learning android programing for the last weeks and I have a question.
How can I configure the background color of the action bar along with the status bar color when using the Theme.Appcompat.Light.NoActionBar theme and by setting the toolbar in my activity?
I would like to do it in xml and not programmatically.

I get the following error when I use

```
Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar
```

as parent of a custom style.

```
This Activity already has an action bar supplied by the window decor. Do not request Window.FEATURE_SUPPORT_ACTION_BAR and set windowActionBar to false in your theme to use a Toolbar instead.
```

This works for me:

```
<resources>
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="CustomMaterialTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="actionModeBackground">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this make custom theme or add to your current theme like this:

```
 <style name="CustomMaterialTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/textColorPrimary</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/windowBackground</item>     
</style>
```

Hope it helps.Thanks Refer here i found a beautiful tutorial http://coderzpassion.com/android-working-with-material-design/

Comment: I have edited my question with an exception that is thrown

Comment: @edmond change your theme to NoActionBar theme or try setting this for your theme in styles.xml  <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>

Answer (score 0):

**You need to setup main style for your app.**

**Go to res->values->styles.xml file.**

**Add below in your main theme.**

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/ColorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/ColorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/ColorPrimary</item>
        <item name="android:navigationBarColor">@color/ColorPrimary</item>
    </style>
```

Here you need to setup colors in color.xml file as below.

```
<resources>
    <color name="ColorPrimary">Your Color</color>
    <color name="ColorPrimaryDark">Your Color</color>
</resources>
```

**It's Done.**

**Hope it will help you.**

Answer (score 0):

Try using this and provide custom colors

```
        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar_home"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
                app:theme="@style/ToolbarHomeColor" />

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```